# Double-whammy: Bad entry in UEFI menu + good entry misnamed

Tags: boot, uefi, grub2

History: Windows 10 installed, then I installed Ubuntu... and remembered why I preferred Mint.

I then reformatted the Ubuntu partition, and installed Mint onto it.

Now my UEFI menu has four entries: Windows 10, Ubuntu (which leads to a bare GRUB environment), "Boot from EFI file...", and "Notebook Hard Drive - Toshiba MQ01ABD100" (even though it's an HP, not a Toshiba).

That last entry actually leads to the GRUB-2 menu, with (3) Mint and "Windows Recovery Disk" choices. Mint boots correctly from there, and the latter option leads back to a normal Windows boot.

So, although everything works... it's messy, and I want to clean it. I tried EasyUEFI, a freeware Windows program, that claimed to delete the unwanted UEFI entry - but in fact did nothing.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way is using the [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

It may be safest to leave the underlying UEFI files in place but control those which grub displays, and in what order, [though once you establish that some UEFI boot files are no longer needed, they can be removed.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/take-control-your-pc-uefi-secure-boot)